# .how to fix Undefined variable errors laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

I am using laravel and I have a problem that I cannot find errors even though I have searched many and tried many different uses but I still get an Undefined variable: post error (View: C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ blog-news \ resources \ views \ layouts \ news.blade.php) Please help me, thanks !!

This is my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\Post;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    // insert data
    public function insertData()
    {
        $post = Post::all();
        return view('layout.news',['post',$post]);
    }
}
```

And here is my code in news.blade.php:

```
@foreach($post as $p)
  <h1>{{ $p -> name}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

and this route of me: `Route::get('/news','DataController@insertData');`

Comment: Typo: `return view('layout.news',['post',$post]);` should be `return view('layout.news',['post' => $post]);`

Comment: You should also be using laravel naming standards, as that will likely help you in the future (in terms of controller method and route names).

Comment: I tried and made your way but I still get the Undefined variable error. ```return view('layout.news',['post'=>$post]);```